# Белые полосы на спрайтах в unity

Tags: unity3d

Белая прозрачная полоса появляется только тогда, когда я налаживаю свой материал, отвечающий за тень объекта

[image: Белая полоса по центру]
Информация о материале:

[image: Материал, который является раздражителем]
Подскажите пожалуйста как убрать эту полосу

Comment: Попробуйте изменить изображение. Или поищите в Интернете. Во Всемирной паутине должно найтись (см. документацию Unity).

Comment: Ну `Standart Fade` материал тут не пришей рукав, вам нужен `Sprite Diffuse`. А линия скорее всего от `Specular Highlight` или `Reflections`(которого тут вообще быть не должно).